# Connecting to LeapMotion

Tags: programming, hardware, input-devices, image-processing

Thanks to those who helped me with my previous question. I will help others too where I can. In the meantime I have a general question whether anyone has had success connecting Mathematica to the LeapMotionTM device on a Mac? If so, please could you show me how you did this? I have followed instructions on the following page but got Java errors, and I use OSX not Windows:

*http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/90931*

The only modifications I made to the instruction code was to change the directory symbols from "\\" to "/", though I have tried both formats.

```
Needs["JLink`"];

ReinstallJava[CommandLine -> "java", JVMArguments -> 
   "-Djava.library.path=[/Users/myname/Desktop/LeapDeveloperKit/
LeapSDK]"]; (*etc...*)
```

I have programmed the LeapMotion in Processing but would prefer to prototype some ideas in Mathematica as I can understand the math better with that before rewriting in Processing. Thanks.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to post up those java errors.

Comment: Java::excptn: A Java exception occurred:     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class     com.leapmotion.leap.LeapJNI
     at com.leapmotion.leap.Controller.<init>    (Controller.java:39)
     at     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source).JavaNew::fail: "Error calling constructor for class "com.leapmotion.leap.Controller"

Answer (score 4):

I solved the connection problem I was having by adding `InstallJava` to the code written on the afore mentioned web site. I am not sure why `ReinstallJava` did not work on its own without having to use `InstallJava` too.

Run this code first (straight out of the Wolfram website):

```
Needs["JLink`"];
ReinstallJava[CommandLine -> "java", 
   JVMArguments -> 
   "-Djava.library.path=[/Users/.../LeapDeveloperKit/LeapSDK/]"];
AddToClassPath["/Users/.../LeapSDK/lib"];
```

This is the part that's a little different:

```
InstallJava[]; (* does not work if this is not included *)
controller = JavaNew["com.leapmotion.leap.Controller"];
controller@isConnected[] (* test to see if LeapMotion is tied into Mathematica *)
```

Comment: Sure, people who search for "mathematica LeapMotion" might end up here so feel free to add some measurements/code to your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I have spent a little time accessing the methods of the Java linker file for LeapMotion with Mathematica based on the work of others:

http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/90931

Following their instruction, it is possible to access methods using Methods[] which returns a list of classes and methods. It is possible to follow the inheritance using this:

```
controller = JavaNew["com.leapmotion.leap.Controller"]
Methods[controller]
```

Code posted by Jari Kirma on the Wolfram Community site (link above) for creating methods to access finger position vectors:

```
getFrameData = 
  Module[{getFrame, getFingerList, getVector, makeRule, fun}, 
  ... (* etc *)
]
```

I have modified the code that was posted by Jari Kirma on the Wolfram Community site to illustrate the finger tips alongside their vector positions using Grid[], as well as a model of the LeapMotionTM on the desk:

```
Grid[{{
Dynamic[{((tipPosition /. #) & /@ (fingers /. getFrameData[controller])) // MatrixForm,
 Graphics3D[{
  (*Display model of LeapMotion on the desk*)
  Gray, Cuboid[{-25, -13, -17}, {25, 13, 17}],

  (*model finger tips*)
  Red, Sphere[{1, -1, 1} #[[{1, 3, 2}]], 15]} & /@ ((tipPosition /. #) & /@ (fingers /. getFrameData[controller])),
     AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{-200, 200}, {-200, 200}, {0, 400}}]}, 
UpdateInterval -> 0.05]
}}, 
Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Decreasing the UpdateInterval value to less than 0.05 did not seem to speed up the graphics frame rate. Could this be a bottle neck in the device? Also, I have not used the AxesLabel option correctly as it does not appear on the 3D graphic, unless this is not an option for Graphics3D[]?

Also, please correct any of the above such as syntax conventions if possible.

Regards